# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

There are three files in my settings folder:

- base.py
- development.py
- production.py

I've put this line in my wsgi.py file:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings.development")
```

But when I run `gunicorn myproj.wsgi:application` and try to load application in browser I get:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I definitely have `SECRET_KEY` in `base.py` and in `development.py` I have this line:

```
from base import *
```

I've updated `manage.py` and specified new settings file there just to test if `runserver` will work and it works.

**UPDATE:**
And now I have put `SECRET_KEY` into `development.py`. When I run `gunicorn myproj.wsgi:application --settings 'myproj.settings.development'` the error is still there.

Comment: do you not need a SECRET_KEY in settings.py

Comment: I know that there are better ways to store it but for now I would like to store it there. Then I guess it will be better to store it as environment variable or maybe something else.

Comment: try putting it in manage.py also.

Comment: you mean secret key? I've tried import `settings.development` from `manage.py shell` and SECRET_KEY is there.

Comment: I mean os.environ.setdefault(....

Comment: Yes, I've already did it. That's why I can use `manage.py`. But it still isn't working with gunicorn.

Comment: @MaximeLorant, nope. That guy had problems running `manage.py runserver` and as I described in question I can do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just needed to run :

```
gunicorn myproj.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myproj.settings.development'
```

There's a line

`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "videotube.settings.development")`

in my wsgi.py. I don't know why but gunicorn doesn't care about it.

Comment: Strange..I'm having the same issue but I have an environment variable specified in /etc/environment for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and SECRET_KEY. When I run the project with the development server it runs fine and picks up the secret key. Maybe gunicorn is unable to read the environment file?